# G729 codec for Linphone Android

Tags: android

I have compiled and build the bcg729 codec for the linphone android implementation. How do i enable and use it? I have the g729 royalties taken care of. When i run my final app,  i don't see this enabled.

Comment: if you are successfully build that then on `.so` file of bcgg729 will created. put this file under libs directory. there will be two sub-directory `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`. choose appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

```java
 PayloadType[] defauldCodecs = linphoneCore.getAudioCodecs();PayloadType payloadType = inphoneCore.findPayloadType("G729");if (payloadType != null) {linphoneCore.enablePayloadType(payloadType, true);PayloadType[] codecs = new PayloadType[]{payloadType};    linphoneCore.setAudioCodecs(codecs); }
```