# How to enable G729 in Linphone Android

Tags: android, linphone

I followed the guide in the link:
[G729 codec for Linphone Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005067/g729-codec-for-linphone-android)

And added .SO file to libs directory.

We can built Android app on actual device, and saw G729 setting in Setting screen.

But when we disabled all of audio codec except for G729, we cannot make a call anymore.

Could you help me to build and integrate G729 into Linphone Android?

Answer (score 2):

First download latest source code of Linphone from [here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android).

After that go to project top level directory and execute followoing command:

```
./prepare.py -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=ON -DENABLE_G729=ON
```

By default all non free codecs are disabled.

Using above command you can enable non free codecs.`-DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=ON` argument enable non free codecs & `-DENABLE_G729=ON` argument enable G729 codec.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am trying to enable codec H263 using command: ./prepare.py -f -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=YES -DENABLE_H263=YES.... But it still showing in "-- Disabled features" list after command run. Have any idea ?

Comment: Try this ./prepare.py -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=ON -DENABLE_H263=ON

Comment: I have tried with that as well but still showing this in disabled featured list

Comment: I find a solution: ./prepare.py -c && ./prepare.py -DENABLE_NON_FREE_CODECS=ON -DENABLE_FFMPEG=ON -DENABLE_H263P=ON -DENABLE_H263=ON

Answer (score 1):

In linphone we have read me file and in that they give option while we build project. you need to give option for g729 as 1 and build the project.

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Yes this will work for you. You can read in the read me file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to understand here: First, the SIP server should have G729 enabled and second, you need to have G729 enabled in the app at both end (receiver and caller).

To build linphone with G729, execute the following command:

`make BUILD_G729=1`